# How to count the node of content type for corresponding entity reference field

Tags: nodes, entities

I am creating a report. I want to count the nodes of a content type saved for particular entity reference field.

So far I have worked with [Views Aggregator](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) and [Forena Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena).

But I am not able find it. Can anyone help me on this please?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29749/discussion-on-question-by-rose-how-to-count-the-node-of-content-type-for-corresp).

Answer (score 0):

In Views, under **Advanced**, **Use Aggregation - Yes**.

Suppose you have content type A and B. B has entity reference field which refers A.
Now you have already created a view for content type A and added its relationship to B.

Now under Fields, Add a new field of the content type B(suppose body), change the label to Count set its **aggregation settings** to **count**.